# Adding bar button item in navigation bar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

i was working with navigation bar button items.i was using the following code to do so

```
UIBarButtonItem *btnSave = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                                    initWithTitle:@"Save"                                            
                                    style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered 
                                    target:self 
                                 action:@selector(save_Clicked:)];
     self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = btnSave;
     [btnSave release];

     UIBarButtonItem *btnCancel = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                                    initWithTitle:@"Cancel"                                            
                                    style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered 
                                    target:self 
                                    action:@selector(save_Clicked)];
     self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = btnCancel;
     [btnCancel release];
```

my question is how to add another button just adjacent to the left bar button item.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To do this you need to create a toolbar then keep adding UIButton to it, then set the toolbar as the leftBarButton

something like this:

```
UIToolbar* tools = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 250, 44)];
tools.tintColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[tools setTranslucent:YES];

NSMutableArray* buttons = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:9];

UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"AL_HomeMod_Icon.png"];
UIButton *myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[myButton setImage:myImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
myButton.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = YES;
myButton.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, myImage.size.width, myImage.size.height);

[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(clickViewHomeMod) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIBarButtonItem *bi = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                       initWithCustomView:myButton];

[buttons addObject:bi];
[bi release];

myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"AL_History_Icon.png"];
myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[myButton setImage:myImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
myButton.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = YES;
myButton.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, myImage.size.width, myImage.size.height);

[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(clickViewHistory) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

bi = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
      initWithCustomView:myButton];

[buttons addObject:bi];
[bi release];

myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"AL_RX_Icon.png"];
myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[myButton setImage:myImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
myButton.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = YES;
myButton.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, myImage.size.width, myImage.size.height);

[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(clickViewCustomPopView2) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

bi = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
      initWithCustomView:myButton];

[buttons addObject:bi];
[bi release];

myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"AL_User_Icon.png"];
myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[myButton setImage:myImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
myButton.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = YES;
myButton.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, myImage.size.width, myImage.size.height);

[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(clickViewCustomPopView:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
bi = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
      initWithCustomView:myButton];
[buttons addObject:bi];
popButton = myButton;
[bi release];


// stick the buttons in the toolbar
[tools setItems:buttons animated:NO];

[buttons release];

// and put the toolbar in the nav bar
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:tools];
[tools release];
```

hope that help

Pondd

Answer (score 7):

Create a button  as

```
UIBarButtonItem *logoutButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                                initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logout.png"] 
                                style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain 
                                target:self action:@selector(doLogout)];
```

Add this button to right of navigation bar

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = logoutButton;
```

or add this button to left side of navigation bar

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = logoutButton;
```

`doLogout` is a function which will be called on touch logout button

Answer (score 2):

I achieved  my task by using the following code :

```
UIToolbar *tools=[[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 150, 44)];

tools.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

 [tools setTranslucent:YES];

UIBarButtonItem *optionBtn=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Options" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(optionPressed:)];

UIBarButtonItem *doneBtn=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(donePressed:)];

 NSArray *buttons=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:optionBtn,doneBtn, nil];

    [tools setItems:buttons animated:NO];

 self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:tools];
```

NOTE:From IOS 5.0 onwards, apple has  done it lot easier . It can be done as

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:optionBtn,doneBtn, nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom view with two buttons and use `UIBarButtonItem`'s [`initWithCustomView:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIBarButtonItem/initWithCustomView%3a) initializer. That should do it.