# How to add custom item to Navigation Bar

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uibarbuttonitem

I have been fighting for a few hours with different type of code to add a custom item to my Navigation Bar. Unfortunately its failing, and theres no debugging error. Right now im only able to change the title of the bar.

The code is added in viewDidLoad method in the particular ViewController:

```
UIBarButtonItem *gotoNext = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Goto next" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(gotoNextAction)];

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = gotoNext;
```

I tried following code but unfortunately without any luck:

```
UIView* container = [[UIView alloc] init];
UIButton * button = [[UIButton alloc] init];

[button setTitle:@"Test" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[container addSubview:button];

UIBarButtonItem* item = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:container];

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = item;
```

Comment: Where is set frame of container ? background color ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you have to add custom view in Navigation bar item

```
UIBarButtonItem *bi = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                       initWithCustomView:myButton];
```

For more detail refer below link

[Adding bar button item in navigation bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6120001/adding-bar-button-item-in-navigation-bar)

[How to add several UIBarButtonItems to a NavigationBar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8431435/how-to-add-several-uibarbuttonitems-to-a-navigationbar)

Comment: If you look in my original post i updated it with a code i tested, unfortunately it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can see wrong with your code is the missing colon at the end of your selector name.  It should read:

```
UIBarButtonItem *gotoNext = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Goto next" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(gotoNextAction:)];
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can write a category for UIBarButtonItem.

```
+ (instancetype)itemWithImage:(UIImage *)buttonImage
              buttonTitle:(NSString *)title
              buttonFrame:(CGRect)frame
                   target:(id)target
                   action:(SEL)action{
    UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:frame];
    [button setTitle:title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button addTarget:target action:action forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    return [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:button];
  }
```