# How do I add a left button item to a UINavigationController on iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationitem

I am trying to add a Reload button to the top bar of a navigation controller with no success.

Here is the header:

```
@interface PropertyViewController : UINavigationController {

}
```

Here is how I am trying to add it:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    if (self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil]) {
        UIBarButtonItem *reload = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Show" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                          target:self action:@selector(reloadPropertyList:)];
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = reload;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: Why are you subclassing navigation controller here?

Comment: then how to add and where?

Comment: You haven't explained what all your view controllers are, but view controllers specify the items to show and the navigation controller deals with showing them

Answer (score 0):

You should use custom navigation bar. hide navigation bar and made your custom. Drag UIView and and add button to it.

If you wantto keep navigation bar than you can use tool bar like,
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6120001/adding-bar-button-item-in-navigation-bar)

Answer (score 0):

The method **initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil** is not called automatically so you need to create an instance of **PropertyViewController** class like below

```
PropertyViewController *propertyVC = [[PropertyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"your_nib_if_exist" bundle:nil];
//pass nib name if nib exist otherwise pass nil
```